# Как заблокировать ip диапазон посредством iptables?

Tags: debian, iptables

Я хотел бы заблокировать исходящий трафик на все *ip*-адреса, начинающиеся на `115`.

Нужно заблокировать все ip вида:

```
115.*.*.*
```

Debian 6.0

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: имело ввиду вида 115 . * . * . *

Comment: @Ruslan не `/24`, а `/8`

Comment: @Sergiks, боже, старею. Спасибо. 115.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заблокировать и сохранить:

```
sudo  iptables  -A OUTPUT  -d 115.0.0.0/8  -j DROP
sudo  iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Потом восстановить из сохраненного, если понадобится:

```
sudo  iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Для Debian начиная с `6.0` есть утилита автозагрузки сохраненных правил "iptables-persistent". Её достаточно установить:

```
sudo  apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

**Warning** Играя с iptables вы легко можете потерять доступ к серверу. Даже когда, казалось бы, «что может пойти не так?!» – ошибки совершаются. Наступал на эти грабли *n* раз. Поэтому **не рвите SSH сеанс** с сервером, пока не убедитесь, что всё ещё можете до него достучаться хотя бы по SSH в новом параллельном сеансе.

Comment: Стоит еще добавить, что задумываться о сохранении и восстановлении стоит после завершения всех проверок ( особенно когда доступ к серверу только удаленный). Иначе исправить случайную ошибку, которая почему-то возникает регулярно, не получится даже "железным" ребутом и придеться ехать в гости в ДЦ :-)

Comment: @Ruslan, верно, мои любимые грабли. Обновляю ответ.